# Creating a new list with new second element

Tags: list-manipulation

Given `data={{1, 34}, {2, 54}, {3, 66}, {4, 77}, {5, 92}}`, I would like to create a new list such that

```
{{1, 34}, {2, 54-34}, {3, 66-54}, {4, 77-66}, {5, 92-77}}
```

which is `{{1, 34}, {2, 20}, {3, 12}, {4, 11}, {5, 15}`.

Comment: Like `Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], Differences[Prepend[data[[All, 2]], 0]]}]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = SubsetMap[Differences @* Prepend[0], {All,2}]
```

***Example:***

```
data = {{1, 34}, {2, 54}, {3, 66}, {4, 77}, {5, 92}} ;

f @ data
```

> ```
>   {{1, 34}, {2, 20}, {3, 12}, {4, 11}, {5, 15}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

The following works, I think

```
data = {{1, 34}, {2, 54}, {3, 66}, {4, 77}, {5, 92}};
data[[2 ;; 5, 2]] = Differences[data[[All, 2]]];
```

Output when data is called is

```
{{1, 34}, {2, 20}, {3, 12}, {4, 11}, {5, 15}}
```

Adjusting for specific lengths (dimensions of a submatrix to be replaced) is straightforward, e.g.

```
data[[2 ;; Dimensions[data][[1]], 2]] = Differences[data[[All, 2]]];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{1, 34}, {2, 54}, {3, 66}, {4, 77}, {5, 92}};
```

Using `SequenceCases`

```
Prepend[First @ list] @
 SequenceCases[list, {{_, a_}, {n_, b_}} :> {n, b - a}, Overlaps -> True]
```

{{1, 34}, {2, 20}, {3, 12}, {4, 11}, {5, 15}}

Answer (score 3):

```
Join[{First@data}, 
 Transpose[{Rest@data[[All, 1]], Differences@data[[All, 2]]}]]
```

or

```
Join[{First@data}, 
 Partition[data, 2, 1] /. {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> {c, d - b}]
```

or

```
BlockMap[{First@Last@#, Last@Last@# - Last@First@#} &, {{0, 0}}~Join~
  data, 2, 1]
```

---

> {{1, 34}, {2, 20}, {3, 12}, {4, 11}, {5, 15}}

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{1, 34}, {2, 54}, {3, 66}, {4, 77}, {5, 92}};
```

---

Using `Partition`:

```
f = Subtract[#2, #1] & @@@ Prepend[{0, #[[1]]}]@Partition[#, 2, 1] &;

Thread@{#[[All, 1]], f@#[[All, 2]]} &@data
```

*Result*:

> {{1, 34}, {2, 20}, {3, 12}, {4, 11}, {5, 15}}

Or using `Table` and `If`:

```
f = If[k == 1, #[[k]], {#[[k, 1]], #[[k, 2]] - #[[k - 1, 2]]}] &;

Table[f@#, {k, Length@#}] &@data
```

*Result*:

> {{1, 34}, {2, 20}, {3, 12}, {4, 11}, {5, 15}}